# How do you show animated gifs with .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, animation, compact-framework, picturebox

I would like to display an animated gif on a .NET Compact `Form`.
Currently I use a `PictureBox` control and toggle between 
`.Visible = true` and `.Visible = false`.

After `.Visible = true` the gif is shown however it's not animated. How can I get the .NET Compact Framework to animate it?

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the .Net Compact framework does not support displaying GIF based animations on a Windows Form.  It is possbile to code up a custom animator that will essentially do the same.  Here's a link to a sample class for displaying a GIF on the compact framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446483.aspx

Comment: It is a pain to extract the single frames but at least it works. Thanks.