# Blink Label without timer or delay

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make label blink without using any of these? as i have a backgroundworker and want it to give alarm to the client while doing its work

Comment: What would make it come on and off, if not a timer? Why do you not want to use a timer?

Comment: You could use an animated gif instead of a label.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) to notify your foreground thread every now and then.

Subscribe to the [`Backgroundworker.ProgressChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) and do your "animation", i.e. changing the colors or visibility, similar to what @HasanKhan suggests in the comment below:

```
MyLabel.Visible = progress % 2==0 ? true : false;
```

(Please note that the `ProgressChanged` event is already being executed in the foreground thread so there is no need to call `Control.Invoke`).

Comment: In Progress Changed Event set Visible = progress % 2==0 ? Visible : Hidden;