# Displaying animation of 200 frames

Tags: c#, animation

I have 200 animation consisting of 200 png images. What is the best way to load it in C# application and loop through it to have a smooth animation. The image size is 640x480. Thanks!

Comment: which kind of application (winforms, wpf...)?

Comment: make it a video instead?

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ yet? Where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: I agree with Thomas. Using video techniques will give you the best performance. Otherwise, displaying images sounds pretty straightforward. What have you tried?

Comment: winforms. Only way I know is ether reading them into imagelist control from directory or loading manually through the studio. I want it embedded in exe

Comment: @kristian just a suggestion: winforms doesn't support animation. If you need an animation-intensive UI, use WPF.

Comment: Maybe a simple GIF animation? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c Or a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To embed resources and use them in Visual Studio/.NET, all you need to know is written [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292/en-us).
There are plenty of other guides, actually.