# Best way to keep image in memory

Tags: c#, image-processing

I want to keep 1000-2000 Images in memory. I tried with imageToByteArray and store them in a key value pair but obviously gives memory leak. Is there any other way or i'm lost?
The reason for keeping them in memory is for very fast reading but it looks like a bad idea.

Pretty small images 450, 250 i will use them in winforms. The problem is that they are grouped in clips so in runtime i will show 25picture/second so thats why i need the memory

Thanks in advance,

Comment: it entirely depends on how much `RAM` your system has!

Comment: What images are you talking about? Small icons or 10M photos? The latter won't work as you will be very soon out of memory...

Comment: What do you want to do with these images? 1000 images is a LOT! Try keeping a thumbnail of the images instead of the whole image - that would require less resources. Where do you want to use them - Forms, WPF, ASP etc...

Comment: What kind of app are we talking about? Give us more context, so far it looks like a VERY bad idea.

Comment: Pretty small images 450, 250 i will use them in winforms. The problem is that they are grouped in clips so in runtime i will show 25picture/second so thats why i need the memory

Comment: Your hard drive can read far more than 25 pics a second, as long they are not very large.

Comment: Consider a grouping schema.  unless you truly need all the images at once, design a system where you can define a "group" of active images, and load those...leaving the others on the hard drive.  Then at logical points, ie: whenever the "group" would change, load the next set of images and let the others expire.

Comment: Also, look into project resources.  They inflate the dll/exe, rather significantly, but then the image files are packaged as part of the distributable, which actually does make accessing them faster, even if only slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any situation where you need to 1000 images at once?

If you keep them all, depends on the image size you will definitely hit the memory caps in the long run. You need to have some cache mechanism to manage the smartly. May be you can deal with a simply DB like SQLite to manage them efficiently or use your own smart way of caching based on your application preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with WinForms - have you considered [using actual animated gifs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c). It's not so hard to make them out of a series of images representing separate frames...