# Gif image not animating if thread is in progress

Tags: multithreading, gif

I have a window form having one `PictureBox`. I have added `.gif` file to it. This form is kind a progress bar so I am opening this in a separate thread then a main thread. Issue I am having is until all the threads are completed `gif image` is not start `animating`.

Please suggest. Below is my code:

```
private bool StartUploading()
{

    objLoadingThread = new Thread(LoadProgressBar);
    objLoadingThread.Start();
    .. 
    ..
    ..
    ..
    StopProgress = true;
}

// Progress bar
private void LoadProgressBar()
{
    objAlertForm = new AlertForm();
    objAlertForm.Show();
    objAlertForm.Refresh();
    while (!StopProgress)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            objAlertForm.ProgressValue = i;
            if (StopProgress)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    objAlertForm.Hide();
    StopProgress = false;
    objLoadingThread.Abort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep will make the main thread to sleep and not the objLoadingThread  thread.

If at all you need a delay you can look for some loop with large iteration.

Comment: I don't need thread for now. After removing Thread.Sleep still it won't work. I have tried that.

Comment: See the second answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c

Comment: Why does thread.sleep screw up animated gifs? I need a rotating gif displayed for 15 seconds. How to do it then?

Comment: If you remove thread.sleep animated gif works