# Play Gif In Picturebox When Mouse On Picturebox C#

Tags: c#, picturebox, gif

I Have a Picturebox in WinForm 
I want when mouse go on Picturebox gif play once
How can i do that?

Comment: Show us how far have you gone.
Can you code the event? Can you start playing the gif?

Comment: checkout http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1004624/Gif-viewer-Snipper-control

Comment: no i have not i need code for play too

Answer (score 0):

[How do you show animated GIFs on a Windows Form (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c) explains how to enable and disable animation. Create procedures for to enable and disable animation. Consider letting a different thread (Backgroundworker? or maybe async-await) do the animation

Create event handlers to react on MouseEnter and Mouse Leave and enable and disable the animation.

Most neat solution: Create a class AnimatedPictureBox derived from a picture box or a user control that has a picture box on it and let this class react on MouseEnter / MouseLeave. Advantage: code is reusable and you can use the designer to put the AnimatedPictureBox on your form