# Image Property of a button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, gif

I am aware that the image property of a button in vb.net reads a .GIF format and thus animating at run time. I have a custom-made button with also a custom-made image property but unfortunately, it does not read a .GIF format. I have this code snippet:

```
    Private _Image As Image
<Category("Appearance CButton"), _
Description("Get or Set the small Image next to text")> _
<DefaultValue(GetType(Image), "none")> _
Public Property Image() As Image
    Get
        Return _Image
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Image)
        _Image = Value
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
```

This code reads the gif file as picture only and not as a gif. Now, does anyone here knows what is the problem with the code? Or is it possible to just inherit the image property of a windows form button so it can read a gif format? badly need.. thanks!

Comment: Web? Winforms? surly not WPF...

Answer (score 0):

please look here, putting in a picturebox and handling the click event could answer your question.

[How do you show animated GIFs on a Windows Form (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c)