# C# animated gif prevents controls repaint

Tags: c#, repaint, animated-gif

I made a C# program and in a tabControl, on one of its pages, I have a pictureBox where I put an animated gif. When I try this program on a slow PC, as long as this animated gif is shown (the page containing it is shown), repaint of controls (for example on form resize) is done only partially. If the page containing this animated gif is not the one shown, repaint is fine. Also on my PC, which is faster, I have no problems.
The examples in this link
[How do you show animated GIFs on a Windows Form (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c)
seem to only set the "visible" property from another thread. It does not look like running the animated gif in another thread. At least in my case it didn't help. My problem is not that gif doesn't work, the gif works but anything else is slow. Exactly the gif seems to be the resource intensive one.

Comment: (See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483452/639771)

Comment: Closing as a duplicate of the question Clint suggested. If you have a problem implementing this, then you need to post a [mcve] hat demonstrates the problem. We cannot debug code that we cannot see.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the examples in the above links simply set the visible property of pictureBox to true from another thread. This does not seem to me like running the animated gif in another thread. I tried and didn't help.