# How would I display a GifBitmapEncoder in a PictureBox control through code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm building a WinForms app that generates a .gif file. I am achieving this through the GifBitmapEncoder class, which stores the resulting gif.

What I'd like to know is how I can put whatever was generated inside of a PictureBox control. A search has  yielded things that are *close* to what I want, but don't quite get there ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c), for example, shows how to do it without code, but that doesn't really help me).

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: The PictureBox Control uses the [ImageAnimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageanimator) class to animate images which allow timed frames. You just need to set the Image property to an Image object created from a GIF Image. Note that `GifBitmapEncoder` is used in WPF, not WinForms. If you use this encoder to create a sequence of frames and it doesn't work somehow, you have to show how you do it. If you don't know how to convert a BitmapSource to a `System.Drawing.Image`, you can just save the Image to a file stream in the meanwhile. Or use WPF.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your reply. Didn't know that GifBitmapEncoder came from WPF, that's gtk. I know how to go from BitmapSource to an Image, but how would I convert the GifBitmapEncoder to a BitmapSource?

Comment: Well, you don't *convert* from an encoder to a BitmapSource, the encoder generates an image of the specified type that you can write to a stream. You can use a MemoryStream as the source of a BitmapImage. See [BitmapImage.StreamSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource). The problem here is not exactly to generate an Image or a BitmapSource, is to create a working GIF. You probably know about Unisys Corp., lzw , patents and royalties (at that time). So you have to build kind of a *custom encoder* for GIFs. Did you?

Comment: Of course, if you mean that you are creating animated GIFs. If those are just single frames, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Jimi Ah, I should've specified that I'm looking for an animated gif, my bad.
I'll look into the MemoryStream method for the time being. Also I did not build a custom encoder.